# Free DGA given a map and cohomology groups

Tags: homological-algebra, cohomology, differential-graded-algebras

Why do Free DGAs on a morphism often give the same (co)homology as other (co)homologies?

Here is the example that comes to mind first:

**Example:** Let $R$ be a ring, let $A$ be an $R$-algebra, let $M$ be an $A$-module, and let  $d : A \rightarrow M$ be a derivation. There is a categorical construction $\Lambda(d)$, the free anticommutative DGA  given an element of $\text{Der}_R (A, M)$, which is a cochain complex with multiplication and unit in the category of cochain complexes, defined by setting $\Lambda(d)^i = 0$ for $i < 0$, $\Lambda(d)^i = \Lambda^i_A M$ in degree $n$ for $n \geq 0$, and where the differential is uniquely specified by setting 
$$d(x \wedge y) = d(x) y + (-1)^{\text{deg}(x) \text{deg}(y)} x d(y)$$
By free, I mean it is part of an adjunction between a category whose objects are derivations and a category whose objects are DGA's.

In particular (and a very interesting *in particular*), if $X$ is a smooth manifold, $C^{\infty}(X)$ is its $\mathbb{R}$-algebra of $C^{\infty}$-functions to $\mathbb{R}$, and $T^* (X)$ is its cotangent space, then we have a derivation $d : C^{\infty } (X) \rightarrow T^* (X)$. Taking the left adjoint I defined above gives the free anticommutative DGA on this derivation, which many of us know and love as the de Rham complex $\Omega^* (X)$.

What's interesting is that the cohomology of this resolution is the same as the cohomology of other ones:
$$H_{dRh}^n (X) \cong H^n_{sing} (X ; \mathbb{R})$$
$$H_{dRh}^n (X) \cong \hat{H}^n (X, \mathbb{R})$$
Where the last cohomology group is supposed to be Čech cohomology. The first of these is called de Rham's theorem, proved in 1931.

This example features a free DGA construction which matches some kind of (co)homology. My question is, why do (co)homology free DGA constructions like this one often match other (co)homologies? I am especially interested to see if someone can take a very general approach here.

---

Here's some more examples:

1) Koszul (co)homology:

**Example:** Let $R$ be a ring, and let $A$ be an $R$-algebra. Let $M$ be an $A$-module, and let $d : M \rightarrow A$ be an $A$-module map. We can form the free DGA (this time, a chain complex, not cochain complex, and this time resulting in homology, not cohomology), with $M$ in degree $1$ and $R$ in degree $0$. We can form the Koszul complex, which is the free DGA given the map $d : M \rightarrow A$. It is $0$ in negative degrees, and $\Lambda^i_A M$ in degree $i$. The differential is uniquely specified by demanding that $d ( x \wedge y ) = d(x) y + (-1)^{\text{deg}(x) \text{deg}(y)} x d(y)$.

If $M$ is free with basis $x_1, ..., x_n$ and $x_i$ map to a regular sequence $a_i$ in $R$ then the koszul resolution is acyclic except in degree $0$, and so it is quasi-isomorphic to $R/(x_1, ..., x_n)$. Hence this resolution can be used to calculate $\text{Tor}$ and $\text{Ext}$.

2) In Quillen cohomology, let $\Omega_{A/R}$ be the cotangent complex, which is an $A$-module. There is a derivation $d : A \rightarrow \Omega_{A/R}$. This gives a free DGA construction, as in de Rham cohomology, where we will write $\Omega_{A/R}^0 = A, \Omega_{A/R}^1 = \Omega_{A/R}$, and so on. I wonder if the homology of this matches quillen cohomology under certain conditions on the map $R \rightarrow A$.